# jquery ui autocomplete: how to keep the select list open until a selection has been made

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to force a user to select something from the drop down of the jquery autocomplete ui. I've tried returning false in a function using the "close" event, but this doesn't work. How can I keep the select list open until the user makes a selection?

For those who need to see it,
http://smartsend.ontech.com.au/quote
Type in the postcode of four letters
 - i want to keep that list open.

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this, so I used the block UI plugin

Answer (score 2):

Adding a custom handler for the close event, which reopens the results, does work, but is a little annoying because the results can never be closed.  I wanted the results to stay open after the user makes a selection, so they can select more, but to close if the user doesn't make a selection and clicks elsewhere, or if the user hits escape, or deletes the input text, or does anything else that would normally close the results.  Here's what worked for me:

```
close : function (event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ( event.which == 1 ) {
        $("ul.ui-autocomplete").show();
        $("ul.ui-autocomplete").data('keep-open', 1);
    }
    else if ( $("ul.ui-autocomplete").data('keep-open') == 1) {
        $("ul.ui-autocomplete").show();
        $("ul.ui-autocomplete").data('keep-open', 0);
    }

    return false;
}
```

The event.which is 1 when the user is making a selection, however, another close event would follow immediately and close the results anyway.  So I added the keep-open flag.  Perhaps there is a better way to handle that complication.

Note, I also added a simple close button so the user can manually close the results when they are done selecting.